# How does React share methods between classes(components)

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning react.

I understand how to share methods between classes with react.

But i'm wondering how it React does it.
From the code below, I am wondering how it calls to the handleClick method, how does it bind the **this** (Board) to the function so when it's called in Square class it points to the Board class and we can set it's state property and such.

---

In this code below, it sends the Square class an onClick property with an arrow function that contains the Board class method handleClick(i).

When the Square class render method is called, this.props.onClick is passed to the React button element's onClick property and the method(handleClick) inside is called.

The handleClick method points to the Board class when i console.log(this).

**Example react code:**

```
class Square extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <button className="square" onClick={() => this.props.onClick()}>
        {this.props.value}
      </button>
    );
  }
}

class Board extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        squares: Array(9).fill(null),
    };
  }

  handleClick(i) {
    console.log(this);
    const squares = this.state.squares.slice();
    squares[i] = 'X';
    this.setState({squares: squares});
  }

  renderSquare(i) {
    return (
      <Square 
            value={this.state.squares[i]} 
            onClick={() => this.handleClick(i)}
      />
    );
  }
```

**How i tried to understand it**

I wrote this code below to try and understand it but i get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined". If i remove the bind(), it just console logs the **this** as "undefined"

```
class One {
  consoleMethod(func, obj){
    func().bind(obj);
  }
}

class Two {
  constructor() { 
   this.obj1 = new One();

    this.func = function(){    
      console.log(this); // When called: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined
    }

    this.obj1.consoleMethod(this.func, this);
  }

}

let obj2 = new Two();
```

Maybe someone can see the error in my ways and help me understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wrote this code below to try and understand it but i get "Uncaught
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined"

You are calling `func` before binding `this` and keep in mind that `bind` returns a function that you need to call.

Change

```
func().bind(obj);
```

to

```
func.bind(obj)();
```

As far as your question regarding how `this` inside `handleClick` refers to `Board` component is  concerned. That's because you are passing an arrow function to `Square` component.

> But i'm wondering how React does it

Its not a react thing, its just how value of `this` is set in javascript.

Arrow functions do not bind `this`, meaning value of `this` inside the arrow function is same as value of `this` outside the arrow function. In your case, `this` inside

```
onClick={() => this.handleClick(i)}
```

refers to `Board` component. So when you call this arrow function from `Square` component, `this` inside the arrow function points to `Board` component. Consequently, `this` inside `handleClick` refers to `Board` class.

If you change

```
onClick={() => this.handleClick(0)}
```

to

```
onClick={function() { this.handleClick(0)}}
```

then you will get an error because `this` will no longer point to `Board` component, it will point to `Square` component and hence you will not be able to call `handleClick` function from `Square` component

Comment: Thank you. That's very clear. I didn't realise. I will need to learn more about the arrow functions, i didn't realise they handle the 'this' like that.