# How calling a callback directly fixes the 'this' in a React Class Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, this

I would like to learn how is the value of 'this' set when a function called in JSX as a callback to an eventHandler.  I noticed that when I call it directly there is no issue accessing state without getting the famous undefined 'this' error, like so:

```js
import React from "react";

class Accordion extends React.Component {
  state = { term: "random term" };

  onTitleClick() {
    console.log("Title is clicked");
    console.log(this.state.term);
  }

  render() {
    const renderedItems = this.props.items.map((item) => {
      return (
        <React.Fragment key={item.title}>
          <div className="title active" onClick={this.onTitleClick()}>
            <i className="dropdown icon"></i>
            {item.title}
          </div>
          <div className="content active">
            <p>{item.content}</p>
          </div>
        </React.Fragment>
      );
    });
    return <div className="ui styled accordion">{renderedItems}</div>;
  }
}

export default Accordion;
```

When you pass it as just a reference, the famous 'this' is undefined error comes back. Then we know how to bind the 'this' and so on. I feel like I just memorized the solution and now would like to learn the difference.

Comment: In JavaScript, the default behaviour of `this` is that it refers to the context in which it is called. In your code `onClick={this.onTitleClick()}` means that the `onTitleClick()` function is executed within the very same context where `state.term` is declared; the `this` in the function declaration is the same of the `this` during the function execution (that is to say, the `Accordion` class). [... continue ...]

Comment: When you pass a handler to a child component as a reference, the `this` in the function declaration keeps referring to the `Accordion` class while the `this` during the execution refers to the child component... but the child component does not contain a `state.term`, hence the error.

Answer (score 3):

`onClick={this.onTitleClick()}` - This is not how you set the event listener. You just need to pass the name of the function instead of calling it yourself.

As far as your question regarding the value of `this` is concerned, value is set depending on how the function is called. This is not specific to React, this is just how value of `this` is set in Javascript.

> I noticed that when I call it directly there is no issue accessing
> state without getting the famous undefined 'this' error

That's because when you call it like this: `this.onTitleClick()` - `onTitleClick()` is called on `this` which refers to the `Accordion` component. But as mentioned at the start of this answer, this is not how you set the event listener. Instead of calling this method yourself, you need to let javasctipt call it.

> When you pass it as just a reference, the famous 'this' is undefined
> error comes back

This is the correct way to add an event listener but you get an error because when javascript calls the event handler function, value of `this` is not your component, i.e. `Accordion`.

To solve this issue, you have two options:

- Explicitly set `this` using `.bind()`

  ```
  this.onTitleClick = this.onTitleClick.bind(this);
  ```
- Use arrow functions instead of regular functions as event handlers

  ```
  onTitleClick = () => {
     console.log("Title is clicked");
     console.log(this.state.term);
  }
  ```

Following are couple of related questions that might help in understanding `this` further:

- [`“this” is undefined inside an anonymous function returned by another function React`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62231368/this-is-undefined-inside-an-anonymous-function-returned-by-another-function-re/62231422#62231422?utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=ZEEF&utm_source=https%3A%2F%2Fmy-useful-stackoverflow-answers.zeef.com%2Fyousaf.khan)
- [`How does React share methods between classes(components)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62193263/how-does-react-share-methods-between-classescomponents/62193844#62193844?utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=ZEEF&utm_source=https%3A%2F%2Fmy-useful-stackoverflow-answers.zeef.com%2Fyousaf.khan)

Comment: thanks for the answer,  I want to know what is the value of 'this' when I just call it in JSX. Just for learning purposes. I know that you wouldn't call your event handler callback directly like I provided. Because it will be called on render and not going to function as a normal handler. How does it point to the Accordion?

Answer (score 0):

When you pass it as a reference, the `this` is undefined. In order for this to work, you need to bind the function to the class. You can do that in the constructor

```
constructor(props) {
    this.state = { term: "random term" };
    this.onTitleClicked = this.onTitleClicked.bind(this);
}
```

Also, when you pass it to the component, don't call the function, just pass it

```
<div className="title active" onClick={this.onTitleClick}>
```

Notice missing parenthesis by the `this.onTitleClick` call.