# Why cannot read a property of undefined in setState? (react)

Tags: reactjs, setstate

I'm a very new to React, it's my first code. Please tell me what is wrong with function sortWords (cannot read a property of undefined). I need it to change the value, it's calling when the button sort is clicked. I will be appreciate.

```js
class App extends Component {
  initialState = {
    words: ["cat", "bat", "doggo", "why", "hello", "abracadbra"],
  };

  state = {
    isSorted: false
  };

  // Sort
  sortWords() {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      isSorted: !this.state.isSorted
    });
  }
   
  render() {
    const items = this.initialState.words.map((item) => {
      return <li key={item.toString()}> {item} </li>;
    });
    const sortedItems = this.initialState.words.sort((a, b) => {
      return b.length > a.length;
    });
    const { isSorted } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <ul style={{ listStyle: "none" }}>
          { isSorted === false ? items : sortedItems}
        </ul>
        <button onClick={this.sortWords}>Sort</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What is the exact error?

Comment: Problem is the value of `this` inside `sortWords` method. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64065090/how-calling-a-callback-directly-fixes-the-this-in-a-react-class-component/64065315#64065315) for possible solutions..

Comment: @Yousaf it helps, thank you very much! can you tell me am i changing the array correctly after the function called?

Comment: See [this demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-ellis-i4rju?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: cool! and one more question, if it will be a lot of variants of array, should i write it in props or if i'll leave a const in render it will be ok?

Comment: My suggestion is that you sort the array once and save it in the state and depending on whether `isSorted` state is true or false, you can render the sorted or unsorted array. This way you won't have to sort the array again and again.

Comment: @Yousaf but if i want to add more methods like filter and so on, how can i write an if statements?